# How to convert a group of images into a single data_test.npz file?

Tags: python, numpy, pygame, hardware, pygame-surface

I am building a self driving RC car. I have 100s of images taken from pi camera and each one of them are named as direction.jpg . How do I convert these images into single .npz file so that I can train a Neural net.

The code below is a simple python script that enables my car to move on key press and snaps photos every second.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
def interactive_control():
        """Runs the interactive control"""
    setup_interactive_control()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        """ camera code """
        command = 'idle'
        duty_cycle = configuration.INITIAL_PWM_DUTY_CYCLE     
        while True:
            up_key, down, left, right, change, accelerate, decelerate, stop = get_keys()            

            print(command)
            stream = io.BytesIO()
            camera.capture(stream, format='jpeg', use_video_port=True)
            image_helper.save_image_with_direction(stream, command)
            stream.flush()          
        pygame.quit()
def setup_interactive_control():
    """Setup the Pygame Interactive Control Screen"""    
def main():
    """Main function"""
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

This saves images called direction.jpg as npz's:

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import numpy as np

path_to_files = "/my/path/"    
array_of_images = []

for _, file in enumerate(os.listdir(path_to_files)):
    if "direction.jpg" in file: # to check if file has a certain name   
        single_im = Image.open(file)
        single_array = np.array(im)
        array_of_images.append(single_array)            
np.savez("all_images.npz",array_of_images) # save all in one file
```

Somebody did the same for png's:
https://gist.github.com/PaulGwamanda/f91ce9fc9d392c4bcc99c085fd726a34